# Writing more details in a file

Tags: java

actually am working on files and i have written exactly one person's details to a file ,now i want to write multiple person's details to that 
file,i have tried using for loop but two files has been created and i want to  write  multiple person's details  in the same file

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Tourism {
    String name;
    String contact_number;
    String address;
    String enquiry_category;
    String Des;
    String price;
    String location;
    String packages;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner s1=new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner s2=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner s3=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner s4=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    public void Choice(){
     System.out.println("========menu========");
      System.out.println("1.Initiate enquiry");
      System.out.println("2.view enquiry");
      System.out.println("3.exit");
      System.out.println("enter the choice");
      int ch;
      ch=scan.nextInt();
      switch(ch){
          case 1:initiate();
              break;
          case 2:

             View();
              break;

          case 3:
              System.exit(0);
              break;
      }
    }
    public void initiate(){
        for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
            System.out.println("=========="+i+"=========");
        System.out.println("enter the name");
        name=s.next();
        System.out.println("enter the contact number");
        contact_number=s1.nextLine()+"";
        System.out.println("enter the address");
        address=s2.nextLine()+"";
        System.out.println(" enquiry categories:-");
        System.out.println("enter the price range");
         price=s1.nextLine()+"";
        System.out.println("enter the location");
        location=s2.nextLine()+"";
        System.out.println("select/enter the package u want to have");
        packages=s3.nextLine()+"";
        System.out.println("enter the description of enquiry");
        Des=s4.nextLine()+"";
        }
        try{
            BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Enquiry.txt"));
            br.write(name);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("mobile number:"+contact_number);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("address:"+address);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("price:"+price);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("location:"+location);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("packages:"+packages);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("enquiry description:"+Des);
            br.close();
       }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void View(){
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the name to view the details");
        String name1;
         name1=scanner.nextLine();
        try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\shashi.s\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication128\\Enquiry.txt"));
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        if(line.equals(name1)){
            System.out.println(line);
            String line1;
            while((line1=br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line1);
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("oops "+name1+" .....does not exist");
            break;
        }
        }
        }catch(IOException e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Tourism t=new Tourism();
         t.Choice();
    }

}
```

Comment: Which two files were created?

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/java-programming

Comment: wondering what was the the second file name?

Answer (score 0):

use **`FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`**

instead of `**new FileWriter("Enquiry.txt")**`

the modified code tells to append text when boolean expression is true. but in your case it is only writing instead of appending next entered data.Hope you found my code helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your iteration you are just getting the values from console and storing to the variables,but not writing to the file.When you enter the second set of values it overwrites the first one.Finally, you come out of the loop and write the values to file.But the variables only hold the last entered values.
You can modify your code to write to the file,within the for loop itself,as modified below:

```
public void initiate() {
    try {
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Enquiry.txt"));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("==========" + i + "=========");
            System.out.println("enter the name");
            name = s.next();
            System.out.println("enter the contact number");
            contact_number = s1.nextLine() + "";
            System.out.println("enter the address");
            address = s2.nextLine() + "";
            System.out.println(" enquiry categories:-");
            System.out.println("enter the price range");
            price = s1.nextLine() + "";
            System.out.println("enter the location");
            location = s2.nextLine() + "";
            System.out.println("select/enter the package u want to have");
            packages = s3.nextLine() + "";
            System.out.println("enter the description of enquiry");
            Des = s4.nextLine() + "";
            br.newLine();
            br.write(name);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("mobile number:" + contact_number);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("address:" + address);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("price:" + price);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("location:" + location);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("packages:" + packages);
            br.newLine();
            br.write("enquiry description:" + Des);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```